# find common elements from sublist in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, element

I have two list, and I have to extract the items from the first list, from which the first element is present in the second. The code I have pasted bellow works perfectly but as I am operating with several million records, it is painfully slow. Does any one have any idea how it can be optimized?

```
a = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]
b = [2,4,7,8]

same_nums = list(set([x[0] for x in a]).intersection(set(b)))

result = []

for i in a:
    if i[0] in same_nums:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. Just turn `b` into a `set` to speed up the contains check. Then one iteration of `a` in the comprehension will suffice:

```
set_b = set(b)  # makes   vvvvvvvvvvvvv  O(1)
result = [x for x in a if x[0] in set_b]
```

Particular turning `same_nums` back into a `list` is a real performance killer as it makes the whole thing `O(m*n)` again. With a single set from `b` it is `O(m+n)`. But `same_nums` is entirely unnecessary to begin with, since you know all the `i[0]` are in `a` as you are iterating `a`.

Comment: Yeah, that was like several thousand times faster! Much Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try list comprehension with the filter instead of creating a second list with the same size and going via sets, something like:

```
[x for x in a if x[0] in b]
```

Could be faster.

In the code you posted, you do a lot of things: You create a copy of a removing the second dimension, make a set from it, intersect it with the other set, and copy the set back to a list. The big list is at least processed four times this way. My proposal only goes through the list once, so I actually expect it to be faster.

Comment: Surprising. I'll think about it, maybe I'll think of another option.

Comment: The `in b` part is the slow one here, since you're going through `b` for each item `x`. define `_b = set(b)` and replace it in the comprehension. It should speed up considerably.

Comment: The "if in" part is the one what slows it, because the sets of data I am dealing with are huge. I was wondering if the "intersection" method can somehow check only the first item from the sublist.

Comment: Good catch. I like it.

Comment: @FinrodFElagund sets are hash-based, but the way you use them in your code makes you go through `a` several times (once to create `set(a)` and another for the intersection). This is not necessary if you use the comprehension over the set as @schwobaseggl implements in his answer (which is what I suggested in my comment above)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Numpy library as it uses C/C++ implementation under the hood so that it runs much faster.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(10000, size=(10000000, 2))
b = np.random.randint(10000, size=1000)

mask = np.isin(a[:,0], b)
a_masked = a[mask, :]

# Exec time: 3.2 s ± 185 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The other approach (Python list) exec time for the same number of elements is as follows:

```
[x for x in a if x[0] in b]

# Exec time: 55.1 s ± 5.47 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As you can see the `numpy` runs considerably faster. You can also turn python lists to numpy and vice-versa [simply](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html).

Answer (score 1):

The most optimal solutions (at least my specific case) were the ones provided by **schwobaseggl** and **Novin Shahroudi**

I am currently using schwobaseggl's suggestion as I am reading the data from SQL query and Novin Shahroudi solutions requires me to do more data type conversions.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0]]
b = [2,4,7,8]
def return_common_elemens(a,b):
        for subval in a:
            if subval[0] in b:
                yield subval

print(list(return_common_elemens(a,b)))
>>>[[2, 0], [4, 0]]
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.